# downloading and installing frutiger.sty

Tags: xetex

I want my document to have font frutiger. However I found that it is not using frutiger. I have searched online to downlaod and install frutiger.sty but I could not find the proper source. I have also read that if frutiger is not available in any of the word processor applications in our computer then we have to install it. However I have frutiger in MS word. I have also tried to searching for this frutiger.sty in my Miktex package manager but I could not find any. So please suggest me a solution on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using system fonts requires xelatex or lualatex. Just load the `fontspec` package, set the font as shown below and compile the document with lualatex or xelatex.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,blindtext}
\setmainfont{<your font name>}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

You can determine the font name for `\setmainfont` with the  luaotfload-tool on the command line.

See also [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document).